# Why z-index:99999999999; Disables inline style definition?

Tags: css, z-index, inline

Acording to : mozilla.org

The precedence of css matching is as follows:

- Universal selectors
- Type selectors
- Class selectors
- Attributes selectors
- Pseudo-classes
- ID selectors
- Inline style

CSS code:

```
body div#redDiv.myClass{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:99999999999;
}
#blueDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blueDiv" style="z-index:99999999999;"></div>
<div id="redDiv" class="myClass" style="z-index:99999999998;"></div>
```

So given 2 divs, redDiv and blueDiv where:

- redDiv has the CSS definition using the combination of body id and class selector has the z-index property set to "99999999999" but has an inline definition that should override its css to "99999999998"
- blueDiv has the inline css set to "99999999999" .

The expected behavior should be the blueDiv above redDiv but the opposite happens, its almost like the override is not done! But if the values are smaller like "99" and "98" blueDiv is above redDiv (http://jsfiddle.net/9U2fU/1/).

Can anyone point to what might be the problem?

I can't change the Original CSS of redDiv so I need to solve the problem by adding the inline style definition.

[JSFiddle example of wrong override](http://jsfiddle.net/DTX4U/5/)

Comment: just make the inline z-index smaller, that number is too big...

Comment: depending on the browser you might have exceeded its maximum z-index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this and agree with the comments. Your number is larger than a 32 bit integer number and I'm sure the maximum z-index, whatever that may be, is smaller than that and could be the cause of your problem but I haven't tested it. Try reducing it to something like ... 9 and see what happens.

Comment: This post's a bit old, but I can't imagine it would have changed at any point, since it's an easy and BEYOND reasonable range: http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/